# Python socket is not automatically reconnecting

Tags: python, docker, sockets

I have the following python code that connects to a telnet server, reads the messages and send them through a REST request:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import re
import json
import time
import socket

import logging

import threading
import queue

serial_msgs = queue.Queue()

def _commands_client(ip, port, commands=[], refresh_interval=1, retry_interval=5):
    # Infinite connection loop
    logging.warning('Start Telnet client loop')
    while True:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            # Connect Telnet socket
            sock.connect((ip, port))

            # Wait for prompt
            data = sock.recv(1024).decode().rstrip()

            # Loop over commands
            while True:
                for cmd in commands:
                    # Run command and read output
                    sock.sendall((cmd+"\n").encode())
                    data = sock.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                        break
                    data = data.decode().replace('\r', '')

                    # Clean response (Line starts with a >)
                    dataList = [x for x in re.split('\n|>', data) if x]
                    if len(dataList) == 0 or dataList[0] == '': continue

                    # Store command's response to queue (for another thread)
                    logging.info("Command {} returns {}".format(cmd, dataList[0]))
                    serial_msgs.put({'c' : cmd, 'v': dataList[0]})

                    # Wait before next command
                    time.sleep(0.1)

                # Wait X seconds before next loop
                time.sleep(refresh_interval)
        except:
            logging.exception('Failed to connect to Telnet server {}:{}'.format(ip, port))
        finally:
            # Gracefully close socket
            sock.close()

        # Wait before next connection
        time.sleep(retry_interval)

def _dprint_client(ip, port, retry_interval=5):
    # Infinite connection loop
    logging.warning('Start DPRINT client loop')
    while True:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            # Connect Telnet socket
            sock.connect((ip, port))

            while True:
                # Wait for prompt
                data = sock.recv(1024)
                if not data: break
                data = data.decode().rstrip()

                # Read and broadcast lines
                dataList = [x for x in re.split('\n', data) if x]
                logging.info("> DPRINT returns {}".format(dataList))
                serial_msgs.put({'d' : dataList})
        except:
            logging.exception('Failed to connect to DPRINT server {}:{}'.format(ip, port))
        finally:
            # Gracefully close socket
            sock.close()

        # Wait before next connection
        time.sleep(retry_interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dthread = threading.Thread(target=_dprint_client, args=(IP, DPRINT_PORT, RETRY_INTERVAL))
    dthread.start()

# Start commands client
    cthread = threading.Thread(target=_commands_client, args=(IP, PORT, COMMANDS, MODULE, REFRESH_INTERVAL, RETRY_INTERVAL))
    cthread.start()
```

This code has been put inside a Docker container with a restart policy set to `unless-stopped`.

- At first run, the code works as expected. If the connection to the server is dropped, it is able to reconnect automatically. The two threads are running perfectly and can read and send commands as expected.
- At device reboot, the docker is restarted automatically but the code seems to be stuck after displaying `WARNING - Start Telnet client loop` and `WARNING - Start DPRINT client loop`. I can't get any other messages.
- If I perform a docker restart, the dprint thread seems to be able to reconnect to the server but the commands thread is still stuck.

What did I miss ?
Is there any kind of python lib that can automatically handle that reconnection ?